# Number of values of expression $\frac{k}{3} + \frac{m}{8}$ which are less than 6

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Values of expression: $$\frac{k}{3} + \frac{m}{8} $$
that are less than 6, for k,m$\in Z^+ $ $$ $$
I tried to calculate the numbers of k for a particular m, but I got stuck and it won't help in generalizing for different equations of similar type.
EDIT 1:
My method:
for k=1, we will get $$m<48- \frac{8}{3}$$
So we can get 47 values of m for k=1.
Similarly if repeat this process we can get a pattern. But how can we be sure that it will not give the same value of the expression for two different values of k,m. Am I missing something?
EDIT 2:
For Example we assume $(k_1,m_1)$ and $(k_2,m_2)$ gives the same value so,
$$\frac{k_1}{3}+\frac{m_1}{8}= \frac{k_2}{3}+\frac{m_2}{8}$$
which gives us $$ \frac{k2-k1}{m1-m2}=\frac{3}{8}$$
and many (k,m) pairs can satisfy this which will lead to overcounting if we brute force.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please show your work ?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Brute force is very easy in this case.

Comment: $8k + 3m < (6 \times 24) = 144 \implies 1 \leq k < 18$.  Let $f(k)$ denote the number of permissible values of $m$, for a specific $k \in \{1,2,\cdots, 17\}.$  Then, you want $\sum_{k=1}^{17} f(k)$.  So, **what is** $f(k)$?

Comment: @user2661923 I tried that (as mentioned in edit) but how can we be sure there will not be any over counting?

Comment: @lulu but how can we generalize for any such equation?

Comment: "any such equation" is too vague.  But if you fix $k$, say, and count the possible $m$ you should easily be able to express that function of $k$ in terms of standard elementary functions, and that expression generalizes.

Comment: @lulu but that would work if I wanted to find the number of (k,m) satisfying the inequality whereas in this case we have to find the number of values of expression below 6.

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for here.  I would not assume that there is a simple way to count the overlaps that works universally.  Producing the list and searching it for duplicates is easy enough for small numbers, as in the case you have asked about.

Comment: "So we can get $47$ values of $m\ldots$": that's not right! Count them again.

Comment: The condition that the expression is "below 6" is mentioned in the title but not in the body of your Question.  Please use the body to give a self-contained problem statement -- the setup and the goal -- and then add such context as your approach or what makes the problem interesting to you.  I think in the process of explaining what "any such equation" involves you will likely have some insights about counting duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are looking at the number of possible values of $\frac{k}{3}+\frac{m}{8}$ (with $k,m\in\mathbb Z, k,m\ge 1$) smaller than $6$, which is the same as looking at the number of possible values of $8k+3m$ smaller than $144$. This is again the same as the number of possible values of $8k+3m$ *with $k,m\ge 0$* smaller than $133$. (The change of variable: $k\to k-1, m\to m-1$ makes the sum smaller by $11$.) This means - the number of possible values of $8k+3m$ between $0$ and $132$. ($133$ possibilities in total.)

Thus, this problem becomes an instance of the [Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) with $n=2$ terms/coins.

Now, we can see that we can definitely make the values $$14=8+2\times 3$$ $$15=3\times 3$$ $$16=2\times 8$$ which implies that we can make *any* bigger value - just add enough "threes" to one of $14$, $15$ or $16$ (depending on the value $\pmod 3$). As for the values $0-13$, we can see that we can make $0, 3, 6, 9, 12$ and also $8, 11$ and *no others*: we cannot make $1,2,4,5,7,10,13$ (seven of them). Thus, the total number of achievable values is $133-7=126$.

Comment: I understand how to get the number of (k,m) pairs will statisfy the inequality but I was asking the number of values that the equation can take which will be less than 6.

Comment: @WHOOP Whoops! Sorry about that, I have now amended my calculation, hope it is correct.

Comment: This is basically an instance of the "Coin problem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem . I will update the answer.

Comment: @StinkingBishop it is known as chicken mcnugget theorem (among other names). Nevermind, it looks like you found it

Comment: @AlanAbraham Yes, if the "coins" are of sizes $6$, $9$ and $20$ (the sizes of the chicken nugget boxes ;) ).

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks for the updated answer, understood the solution.

Comment: In general, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then we can represent exactly *half* the positive integers $<(a-1)(b-1)$ and *all* the integers $\ge (a-1)(b-1)$ as linear combinations $am+bn$, where $m$ and $n$ are nonnegative integers. In our case, $a=3$, $b=8$, so $(a-1)(b-1)/2=(3-1)(7-1)/2=7$, and that's what we subtract from $133$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein that's a nice theorem, any source for it?

Comment: @WHOOP To be honest, I can’t remember right now whose result it is.